# Why doesn't Rails 3 allow for full html5 form specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I don't think I understand why Rails 3 claims to offer html5 form helpers, but stops only at new input types. Are there plans (or any current way) to allow for additional features, such as the "required" attribute, etc?

Comment: Can you paste some example HTML that you'd like to see generated by Rails helpers?

Answer (score 1):

You can set required

```
text_field_tag 'text', 'text', :required => true
```

Also Rails added support of html5 audio and video with "audio_tag" and "video_tag"

Answer (score 0):

I believe all the features your are talking about are currently out of the Rasil's scope, actually being provided by gems like `formtastic` and `simple_form`.